# Java JScrollPane stop scrolling after click into it

Tags: java, jscrollpane, caret

I have a JTextArea inside a JScrollPane and the Caret Update just works fine.

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)jTextArea1.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

My problem is, after i click on the JTextArea the scrollbars become larger but the viewport still doesnt follow.

[image]

As you can see, the vertical scrollbar isnt at the bottom. The distance to the lower corner of the TextPane is increasing, but the viewport still stick on his position. Meanwhile i switched to a JTextPane because of HTML support but still faces the same problem.

I hope you understand me, greets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the JTextArea, you are setting the caret position at that point. The caret always tries to make itself visible so the text area quits scrolling if you later append text not at the caret. So when you append text, you also need to call textarea.setCaretPosition(wherever_you_want_it_to_be).